# How to put gradient on top of background image but below text

Tags: html, css, gradient

I have some `<div>s` with background-images and white text. I want to put a dark gradient on top of the image so that the white text will be readable. I must do this in CSS. How can I accomplish this?

```
<div><p>Here is some text</p><div>

div p {
    color: white;
}
div {
     background-image: url("images.png")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this....

```
div {
     background-image: url("images.png")
}
```

to this...

```
div {
     background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.6),rgba(0,0,0,0.2)), url("images.png")
}
```

have a look on google for examples because quite a few browsers still need specific prefixes for `linear-gradient` because of varying browser specifications and implications.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the gradient as the background of the `p` element:

> div p {
>
> color:white;
>
> background:linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(252,255,244,.5) 0%,rgba(179,190,173,.5) 100%);
>
> }